# Job service can't execute method

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, .net-standard

I created service to check notification from my own server.

It works fine when my app is running but it doesn't work that well when my app removed from recently. I made toast to check if my service stilling run or not, and the toast worked after I killed the application, but the method that checks server doesn't work in background.

I use xamarin forms and android service with android oreo installed in my emulator this my code:

```
public class MyService : JobService
{
   private void DoWork()
   {
      try
      {
        Intent i =new Intent(this.ApplicationContext,typeof(MyReciver));
        i.SetAction("ezz");
        SendBroadcast(i);
      }
      catch
      {
      }
      finally
      {
        StopSelf();
      }

   }

public override bool OnStartJob(JobParameters jobparams)
{
    new Task(() =>
    {
    while (true)
        {
            DoWork();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            JobFinished(jobparams, true);
        }
    }).Start();
    return true;

}

public override bool OnStopJob(JobParameters jobparams)
{
    return true;

 }
}
```

And this is my receiver:

```
if (intent.Action == "ezz")
    {
        try
        {
            txtmod v = new txtmod();//to get the last id doesn't work in background from shared code
            string cc = v.readtxt();
            string bb = "Last id " + cc;
            Toast.MakeText(context, bb, ToastLength.Short).Show();//run in foreground and stil running in back ground
            PostReq post = new PostReq(1);//doesn't work in background from shared code
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Update: txtmod and postreq

```
public class txtmod
{
    string fileName= Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "txtronana.txt");
    public string readtxt()
    {
        string text="" ;
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
            {
                string s;
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    text = s;
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
        return text;
    }

    public void savetxt(string postid)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(fileName))
            {
                sw.WriteLineAsync(postid);
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

postreq :

```
public async void chkpostAsync(int idp)
    {
        Tst:
        try
        {
            CATITEMS x = await getmainitemsasync(1);
            if (x.properties.data != null)
            {
                if (x.properties.data[0].post_id > idp)//d.post_id)
                {
                    for(int f = 0; f <= 9; f++)
                    {
                        if (x.properties.data[f].post_id > idp)
                        {
                            push(x.properties.data[f].post_title, x.properties.data[f].post_category, x.properties.data[f].post_id,f+1+DateTime.Now.Second);

                        }
                        else { break; }
                    }
                }
                if (lastid != x.properties.data[0].post_id)
                {
                    Txtmod.savetxt(x.properties.data[0].post_id.ToString());
                }
            }
            else { goto Tst; }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: what is `txtmod`?

Comment: txtmod the class that get last id from text document from shared code

Comment: if that is the code that has the problem don't you think it would make sense to share it so we can see what it is doing?

Comment: and postreq the method that check notifications

Comment: Ok @Jason i updated my code

Comment: Do you want service running background in a long time? Or always running in the background?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT alawys running

Comment: Background service execution Limits in Android 8.0, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/#background-execution-limits-in-android-80

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT my service is running in the background with job and toast executed without fail why the other method doesn't executing in the background !

Comment: If you run theTime-consuming operation in your background service